How to fix a live server webpage that is opening but not being loaded in browser?
I have the live server extension installed in VS code and open up to a http://localhost:5500/ webpage. The contents of my HTML file are instead replaced by the following error message:
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at http://localhost:5500/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

And I cannot see my website.
I initially tried Googling around but the results addressed the issue of not being able to open up a webpage with the live server, whereas mine is being opened but not loaded.
Additionally, I am using WSL with VS code, but I don't know if that has anything to do with this issue.

After asking on The Odin Project's discord server, someone mentioned that I had to put:

"liveServer.settings.port": 3000

Into the live server's JSON settings file.
Hope this helped someone else too!
